# Open Telemetry Baggage not getting propagated across quarkus microservice stack

Tags: java, quarkus, open-telemetry, quarkus-reactive

I am adding Baggage to an existing trace as shown below. What I find is that the baggage is not getting propagated. 'traceId','spanId' do get propagated though.
What could be wrong with the setup below ?

Quarkus version 2.16.5Final

Service A :

```
try (var scope =
        Context.current()
            .with(
                Baggage.builder()
                    .put("RequestId", String.valueOf(message.getRequestId()))
                    .build())
            .makeCurrent()) {
            //......some logic here
            emitter.send(KafkaRecord.of(key, message));
           }
```

Service B where I receive the Kafka Message:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MDCEnricher implements OutgoingInterceptor {
  @Override
  public Message<?> onMessage(Message<?> message) {
    Baggage.current()
        .forEach(
            (s, baggageEntry) -> {
              MDC.put(s, baggageEntry.getValue());
            });

    return message;
  }

}
```

Service B is also calling Service C using REST.

Service C

```
@Slf4j
public class MDCFilter {
  @ServerRequestFilter
  public Uni<RestResponse<Void>> copyBaggageIntoMDC(UriInfo uriInfo, HttpHeaders httpHeaders, ContainerRequestContext requestContext){
    SpanContext spanContext = Span.current().getSpanContext();
    Baggage.current()
        .forEach(
            (s, baggageEntry) -> {
              MDC.put(s, baggageEntry.getValue());
            });
    return Uni.createFrom().item((RestResponse<Void>) null);
  }
}
```

quarkus log format in all service :

```
quarkus.log.console.format=%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%X] [%c{2.}] (%t) %s%e%n
```

I expect to see 'RequestId' which I added as baggage in Service A to be logged in all applications but that isn't working. The only MDC values I see are 'traceId' and 'spanId'

Comment: Which version of Quarkus?

Comment: @BrunoBaptista updated the question with the info. I am using 2.16.5Final

Comment: What baggage propagation are you using? W3C?

Comment: @BrunoBaptista not sure what you mean ? I am under the impression that all of that happens under the covers by quarkus. Is there a specific property you are referring to here ?

Comment: Just to make sure the defaults are in use. Will take a look.

Comment: Can you please check if this solution works for you?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76767269/quarkus-opentelemetry-baggage/76770235#76770235